# Interpreting integer color values

Tags: java, colors, rgb

As I'm writing a small "paint" program of my own (just for fun), I wanted to convert an imported image into a pixel array. So far, so good - I found a working solution on stackoverflow that creates an `int[][]` array. Now, the colors are (obviously, since it's an integer array) integer values. I'll probably use something like `Color color = new Color(integerValue)` for conversion, but what I'm interested in is how exactly the color is converted between RGB and integer values.
Specifically, which parts of the value specify the red/green/blue/alpha value of the color? Or if it doesn't work that way (i.e. there is no clear distinction between these 4 values), how DOES it work?
For example, the color black (rgb: #FFFFFF) has a value of -16777216. Is it possible to find out the rgb counterpart just by looking at the integer value?

As said, I'm just asking this so I can comprehend it - I don't intend to actually unravel the integer value manually and create a color that way. I also know that I could use `int red = (new Color(integerValue)).getRed()` to retrieve individual values, but that's pointless considering that I already know that the color is black.
It's just that I expected the integer to show some kind of pattern, considering that red, green and blue have the same values. Furthermore, I've been slightly puzzled that white has a value of -1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to know how the `Color` class works, I suggest you a) read the javadoc, b) read the source.  This will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Have a look at [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and in particular at the [ColorModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html) class, since it's the latter which helps translate from bytes to colors.

Comment: the value `-1` is `0xFFFFFFFF` which is an alpha/red/green/blue of 0xFF or 255.